# :first-letter для 2х символо, есть какой-нибудь аналог?

Tags: javascript, css, css3

Есть ли какая-то возможность стилизовать 2 первых буквы в тексте?
А не только первую, как это делает `:first-letter`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чистым CSS этого не сделать.

Правда есть библиотека `::nth-everything` с хорошим набором `nth` аттрибут. Использовать или нет - Вам решать.
Вот GitHub: https://github.com/FWeinb/nthEverything
И вот codeopen (поиграться): https://codepen.io/FWeinb/pen/djuIx
(это не реклама :) )

Comment: Спасибо, похоже это как раз то что надо!)